# Specify SQL Server File Locations when using Entity Framework Database.Create()

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have several Entity Framework Code First DbContext objects that use a custom Initializer.

In the initializer, the call to

```
context.Database.Create();
```

creates the database in SQL Server.

The Data and Log files are created in directories per the Database Settings in SQL Server.

I would like different DbContext subclasses to have different Data and Log file paths.  Can I specify the paths somehow when creating the database, or must I detach/move/attach in a separate step after the database has been created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use the `AttachDBFilename` keyword in the connection string. See the documentation of [`SqlConnection.ConectionString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Any idea how I can specify the LOG file to be in a separate folder?

Comment: It is not possible from the connection string. The log file will be the same as the filename you specify with "_log.ldf" appended.